# function.caller.arguments is depricated so what is the replacement for this

Tags: javascript

While using the caller function arguments like function.caller.arguments and have seen that now its been deprecated. So what is the way we can use for the replacement of this?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you...

Comment: I want to get event.target of the function which has called the current function
I am using event.target which only works in chrome
For Mozilla i m using like 

fsi.prototype.saveForm = function (){   
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        var eventTarget = fsi.saveForm.caller.arguments[0].target;
    }
}
And as function.caller.arguments has been deprecated what will the alternative of this.

Comment: @user3747994 The alternative is to use a parameter in your function and properly pass the value as an argument. There is no replacement, `function.caller` is just bad code that no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

The replacement of this is to refer to the arguments object.

> The syntax function.arguments is deprecated. The recommended way to access the arguments object available within functions is simply to refer to the variable arguments.

Here is more information about it:

[JS Pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments)

And here is the specification of arguments:

[JS arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)